# Django Redirects Migration Throwing Error

Tags: python, django, redirect, python-3.4, django-1.8

I'm trying to install django.contrib.redirects into my Django 1.8 website.

I added "django.contrib.redirects" into my INSTALLED_APPLS and I added "django.contrib.redirects.middleware.RedirectFallbackMiddleware" into the MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES.

I run the migrate command and get the following:

```
SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
redirects.Redirect.site: (fields.E300) Field defines a relation with     model 'Site', which is either not installed, or is abstract.
```

I've looked over the django redirects app documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/redirects/

But I cannot find why this is happening. I have no idea what the "Site" model is.

Comment: From the very beginning of the documentation you linked to: Ensure that the django.contrib.sites framework [is installed](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/sites/#enabling-the-sites-framework).

Comment: Yeah I just saw it like seconds before you posted. I was just in a rush and overlooked it. Thank you!